# How to find a segment of text in a clob and wrap it with the desired text?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table in which the text is stored and I need to find all the places where certain text is found and add text before and after it
To be more specific, I need to change all the places where the 'SomethingToFind' pattern occurs, find the space before it (or the beginning of the line) and the next ';' and wrap it up with text.

I.E. transform this -

```
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA;
```

into this -

```
/* Caution
  TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA;
Caution */
```

I have the following cycle to search all the records with the text I’m looking for.

```
for x in (select t.id
                     ,t.clobvalue
              from table_name t
            where REGEXP_like(t.clobvalue, 'SomethingToFind')
            )
loop
  --Some Operations
end loop;
```

Text example in clobvalue:

```
BlahBlah Blah;  
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA; 
ExtraText; MoreExtraText;EvenMoreExtraText;   
LastExtraText;  
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExcibitB; TextAboutSomethingToFind.PatternС;  
EndText;
```

The desired result:

```
 BlahBlah Blah;
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA; 
Caution */
ExtraText; MoreExtraText; EvenMoreExtraText;  
LastExtraText;  
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExcibitB; 
Caution */ 
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.PatternС;
Caution */
EndText;
```

I know that i somehow need to use `regexp_replace`, but i have no idea how to do this correctly. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simplified option which works with a single row from the source table; if it has to work for *multiple* rows, things get more complicated (not that it can't be done, but this code would look even *worse*).

Also, it presumes that each "substring" (row) can be converted to `VARCHAR2` (using `TO_CHAR`).

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from test;

COL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BlahBlah Blah;
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA;
ExtraText; MoreExtraText;EvenMoreExtraText;
LastExtraText;
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExcibitB; TextAboutSomethingToFind.Pattern?;
EndText;
```

Solution, written *my way*. Follow the comments within the code. If you're unsure of what it does, execute it CTE by CTE and observe the values each of those `SELECT`s returns.

```
SQL> with temp2 as
  2    -- split multi-lines column to rows, separated by CHR(10)
  3    (select level lvl2,
  4            to_char(regexp_substr(col, '[^' || chr(10) ||']+', 1, level, 'm')) col2
  5     from test
  6     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, chr(10)) + 1
  7    ),
  8  temp3 as
  9    -- out of all rows from the previous step, split those - that contain "SomethingToFind"
 10    -- more than once - into their own separate rows
 11    (select lvl2,
 12            level lvl3,
 13            trim(to_char(regexp_substr(col2, '[^;]+', 1, level))) col3
 14     from (select lvl2,
 15                  col2 from temp2
 16           where instr(col2, 'SomethingToFind') > 0
 17             and regexp_count(col2, ';') > 1
 18          )
 19     connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ';')
 20    ),
 21  almost_there as
 22    -- apply the "Caution" clause to all "SomethingToFinds" from both cases
 23    (select lvl2,
 24            to_number(null) lvl3,
 25            case when instr(col2, 'SomethingToFind') > 0 then
 26                      '/* Caution' ||chr(10) || col2 || chr(10) || 'Caution */'
 27                 else col2
 28            end col
 29     from temp2
 30     where lvl2 not in (select lvl2 from temp3)
 31     union all
 32     select lvl2,
 33            lvl3,
 34            case when instr(col3, 'SomethingToFind') > 0 then
 35                      '/* Caution' ||chr(10) || col3 || chr(10) || 'Caution */'
 36                 else col3
 37            end col
 38     from temp3
 39    )
 40  -- Finally, put them together using LISTAGG, separated by CHR(10)
 41  select listagg(col, chr(10)) within group (order by lvl2, lvl3) result
 42  from almost_there;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BlahBlah Blah;
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExampleA;
Caution */
ExtraText; MoreExtraText;EvenMoreExtraText;
LastExtraText;
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.ExcibitB
Caution */
/* Caution
TextAboutSomethingToFind.Pattern?
Caution */
EndText;


SQL>
```